# And from sql list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am bit new to databases. I am trying to make following query

```
select cm.BatsmanNum
from cricketmatch cm
where cm.BatsmanNum plays with all (select b.BowlerNum from bowler b
                                    where b.MaxBowlingSpeed = 64);
```

My tables:

```
Bowler

Bowler_no Max_bowling_speed
        1                70
        2                89
        3                93
        4                70
        5                89
        6                93
        7                89
        8                93

cricketmatch

Row_no Batsman_no Bowler_no Match_no Runs_scored
     1          1         1        2          50
     2          5         2        2          12
     3          1         4        1          34
     4          3         1        5          56
     5          4         1        5          32
     6          5         5        2          67
     7          5         2        5          10
     8          5         7        5           3
```

Description:

The above query is like take all batsmen from cricketmatch if those (batsmen) play with ALL bowlers (`select b.BowlerNum from bowler b where b.MaxBowlingSpeed = 64`). Is it possible to have an and statement for whole list? How can I do this? I am bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a simple INNER JOIN, right?

```
select cm.BatsmanNum
from cricketmatch cm
inner join bowler b
on cm.Bowler_no = b.Bowler_no
where b.MaxBowlingSpeed = 64;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all the batsmen who have played with all the bowlers. This is quite straight forward implementation of division operation of relational algebra.

Here is the link(if you want to go through it once):

[Divsion Operator](http://users.abo.fi/soini/divisionEnglish.pdf)

For the answer, use the following query to get the result:

```
select cm.Batsman-no
from cricketmatch as cm
where not exists(select Bowler-no
                 from bowler
                 where Bowler-no not in (select crm.Bowler-no
                                         from cricketmatch as crm
                                         where crm.Batsman-no = cm.Batsman-no))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query.

```
    select cm1.Batsman_no  ,count( distinct cm1.Bowler_no) As BowlerCOunt
    from #Cricketmatch CM1 
   inner join bowler b on CM1.Bowler_no=B.Bowler_no -- and Max_bowling_speed >=65
    GROUP by cm1.Batsman_no
    having count( distinct cm1.Bowler_no) =
    (
    select count(distinct cm2.Bowler_no)  from #Cricketmatch CM2  -- list of    all Bowler
    )
```